# How can I clear the cache(s) of my g2x from adb?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, cache

I installed clockworkmod as the recovery, then installed cyanogen 7 nightly for the g2x.  I used Rom Manager to do so.  The problem I'm having is cyanogen shows the boot loading screen in an infinite loop.  From what I have read on the Internet, I need to clear out the cache on the phone, and it should boot.

I can `adb reboot recovery` but it does not go into clockworkmod.  Instead, it shows the icon of an arrow leaving a box - I suppose an indication it is trying to install an update.  I cannot get it to boot into recovery mode.

Is it possible to do so?  Or can I clear the cache or reflash the LG G2X using adb?  My poor phone!  I am lonely without it!

(This is a G2X - if the "tmobile-g2(s)" tag is incorrect, please remove it)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the G2X, but when I would reboot in to recovery on my Galaxy S Vibrant, I used to have to "apply updates", which would run the update.zip that was on the sdcard, this would bring me in to the clockwork recovery.

I also know that the `adb reboot recovery` does not yet work correctly on the Galaxy S Vibrant version, so this could be the same issue on the G2X.